# Apply general sibling (~) until it reaches an element and then no longer match

Tags: css

Is there a way to use something similar to general sibling in css where it continues matching anything directly after an element until an element doesn't match and the no longer check afterwards?

E.g.

```
<p class="para expanded">ABC</p>
<p class="para-after">ABC</p>
<p class="para-after">ABC</p>
<p class="para-after">ABC</p>
<p class="para">ABC</p>
<p class="para-after">ABC</p>
<p class="para-after">ABC</p>
<p class="para-after">ABC</p>
<p class="para expanded">ABC</p>
<p class="para-after">ABC</p>
<p class="para-after">ABC</p>
```

CSS

```
.para.expanded ~ .para-after { color: red; }
```

This will match all `.para-after` including the ones which comes directly after second `.para` which isn't `.expanded` but I want it to reach the second `.para` and then stop looking so it only matches the first 3 `.para-after` and then again matches the ones directly after the last `.para.expanded` as well. I won't know how many `.para-after` there are so I can't manually specify any amount. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Consider two rules:

```css
.para.expanded ~ .para-after { color: red; }
.para.expanded ~ .para ~ .para-after { color: initial; }
```

```html
<p class="para expanded">ABC</p>
<p class="para-after">ABC</p>
<p class="para-after">ABC</p>
<p class="para-after">ABC</p>
<p class="para">ABC</p>
<p class="para-after">ABC</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the only issue with that is that multiple `para` can be expanded and in no particular order so this would break if the first para was expanded and then a 3rd para was expanded.